# What Apache POI exclusions should I use to minimize my project size?

Tags: java, dependencies, apache-poi, xlsx

I 'm trying to export data in xlsx format and I'm using **Apache POI**. Now I would like to add some exclusions (in `pom.xml`) to minimize project size.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Most probably not possible. I would just assume that the people who created apache-poi did not cluster it with useless dependencies

Comment: My 2 cents: don't do it, unless you have a very, _very_ good reason. Maven is not here to annoy you, you can assume that all the dependencies are of some use. Even if you don't use at all one of the subdependencies, nobody knows whether it won't be used sooner or later... And you won't spare much space doing so, but you'll get high probability to have a lot of issues in the near future...

Comment: Switch from `XLSX` to `XLS`? The older file format has a much smaller code size because it doesn't need any XML stuff