# Apache POI: exclusion of unnecessary dependencies

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi

I am using apache POI to generate simple monthly report (SXSSF)... but I was surprised that final app size increased by 40MB ?!? by simply adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And that is a lot. **Is there a way how to exclude unnecessary parts/dependencies?** E.G. 9MB batik (SVG support)
Unfortunately, I am not able to find anything about it in apache documentation.
Thanks.

PS: I choosed Apache POI because it seems like the only live (2021) project ...

PSS: please don't say: use a CSV instead (-:

similar questions without response: [What Apache POI exclusions should I use to minimize my project size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52058906/what-apache-poi-exclusions-should-i-use-to-minimize-my-project-size)

Comment: There seems to be a poi-ooxml-lite package, did you have a look at that?

Comment: Try [the advice given on the mailing list last week around batik etc?](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/r4e453de54b6ee53f74b670b0117030e6c97371fbbda52a7e62550f54%40%3Cuser.poi.apache.org%3E)

Comment: @Thomas poi-ooxml-lite seems promising but unfortunatelly it is not what we discussing now. That is internal dependency. Could not be used as standalone. (If I misunderstood something just post answer with example pom).

Comment: @Gagravarr Yeah, that is exactly what I search for. Thank you. I used Yegor's exclusion and works. Pitty, it is not mentioned in docs. (write answer and I will accept it.)